# Is there a way to create a conda virtual environment with a custom python (by specifying a path to python interpreter, not only python version)?

Tags: conda, virtual-environment, pvpython

I am trying to create a virtual environment with /usr/local/bin/pvpython interpreter (used with ParaView).

As from conda documentation it seems that only python version can be changed (and not the path to python), at first I tried to use virtualenv instead (as it has the --python=/path/to/python flag), but I ran into various IOERROR problems that don't get solved with quick suggestions on the internet.

So before diving into virtualenv, i decided to look back at conda environments: is it possible to change something in conda setup so that it would use python=/path/to/python?

i tried to change PYTHONPATH in .bashrc but that didn't help.

thanks!